# Retag request: opensource -> open-source on ServerFault

Tags: support, retag-request

Please change all instances on the tag `[opensource]` to `[open-source]`. This is an issue on <strike>SO, SU, and</strike> SF <strike>(on SF the <kbd>open-source</kbd> tag hasn't even been created!)</strike>.

"Open source" is two words, so it should definitely be hyphenated.

**UPDATE (July 15/2010):**
`[opensource]` (86)
`[open-source]` (4)

Bonus: `[opensource-software]` (2) --> `[open-source]` (4)

Comment: Noob question: what is the markup to display the tags?

Comment: <kbd>open-source</kbd>, see e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1939/kbd-elements-are-way-intrusive/1941

Answer (score 3):

Done on SO